# Forcing the recall of WM_PAINT

Tags: c++, winapi

I've created a window using `CreateWindowEx` and that is working fine. The window opens.

In the function where I process messages, specifically `WM_PAINT`, I grab the cursor position using `GetCursorPos` and then draw a rectangle there. However, I would like the window to continuously update and redraw this rectangle, acting like a cursor.

I've created a thread like the following to try and force this:

```
DWORD WINAPI RedrawLoop(LPVOID lpParam) {
    HWND handle = (HWND)lpParam;

    while (true) {
        RECT lpRect;
        GetClientRect(handle, &lpRect);
        InvalidateRect(handle, &lpRect, TRUE);
        UpdateWindow(handle);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, this is not working. I've already checked that the handle passed in is the same as the window handle outside the thread.

I've also tried sending `SendMessage(handle, WM_PAINT, 0, 0);` and `RedrawWindow(handle, NULL, NULL, 0);` continuously with no luck.

Comment: Why would you want to run a busy loop? That will block processing of queued messages (i.e. input messages, timers, paint messages)

Comment: You can call `InvalidateRect` from your `WM_PAINT` handler (after you've called `BeginPaint`). This will ultimately trigger another `WM_PAINT` message, but only when there aren't any higher-priority messages to be handled.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My end goal is to continuously repaint the window with a custom drawn cursor. I need to update the location of the rectangle every time the mouse moves. Using a custom system cursor is not an option here, that is why I opted for an overlay + drawing onto that.

Comment: Are you using an `WS_EX_LAYERED` window? That's the neat way to do an overlay. However you do it, I'm sure that a busy loop is wrong. You need to adapt to an event driven model.

Comment: You noted in passing, that *"using a custom system cursor"* were not an option, although the question doesn't explain, why. [CreateIconIndirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createiconindirect) gives you as much freedom in defining a cursor's shape, color and hotspot location as you get from your favored solution.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yep, I'm using `ES_EX_LAYERED` for the window.

Comment: Leaving aside @IInspectable's comments which sound sensible to me, a layered window does not require a busy loop to update it. You just call `UpdateLayeredWindow` when something has changed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I captured the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` event and then proceeded to call `SendMessage(WM_PAINT)` but I never receive `WM_MOUSEMOVE` events in the first place... I've tried capturing mouse input using `SetCapture(hWnd);` but that does not do anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Mouse messages are delivered to the window underneath the mouse cursor, unless that window is transparent and/or another window has captured input.

Comment: So let's solve that problem. Busy loop isn't the solution. You should ask about the real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can get the current cursor position by processing the [`WM_MOUSEMOVE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mousemove) message and invalidate the current window.

Then draw a rectangle through the [`Rectangle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-rectangle) function in the [`WM_PAINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-paint) message. (Note: The origin of coordinates is the upper left corner of the screen)

Here is the sample:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("hello windows");
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wndclass;
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("This program requires Windows NT!"), szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName,
        TEXT("the hello program"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT rect;
    static POINT pt;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
    }
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    {
        Sleep(100);
        GetCursorPos(&pt);
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, FALSE);
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
        Rectangle(hdc, pt.x-rect.right/4 , pt.y-rect.bottom/4, pt.x + rect.right / 4, pt.y + rect.bottom / 4);
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `Sleep(100)` in a `WM_MOUSEMOVE` handler? Do you understand, when `WM_MOUESMOVE` messages are generated?